# First time regex user

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble using regex to show when I need it to do in the proper display's.
Now I have this code which is an easy and simple use regex but I still don't understand how it works. Is there a way to filter the string to show only capital letters?

Let's say I type in a long sentence of names:

> Tyler Sean Cassie Jon Peter.

how would I be able to get the string to only display one name if I don't know what names might be contained in the string? (say that it is a random names will be filled in each time)

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your Regex: ");
        Pattern pattern = 
        Pattern.compile(input.nextLine());


        System.out.println("Enter String to Search");
        Matcher matcher =
        pattern.matcher(input.nextLine());

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("I found the text" + " " + matcher.group() +" starting at " + "index " + matcher.start() + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
            found = true;
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("No match found.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So the question is `How do I match a word in "Tyler Sean Cassie Jon Peter."`? `\w+` could do.

Comment: If we assume that name starts with an upper case letter and then continues with only low-case letters then you can build a patter for a name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ranges inside character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[A-Z][a-z]*
```

This means *a capital letter*, followed by *zero or more lower case letters*.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/xA2iX8/1)

---

If you are not satisfied with ASCII letters only, you can use:

```
\\p{Upper}\\p{Lower}*
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this only matches ASCII letters. It will not match a name like `René`, for example (only `Ren` will be matched).